# Winamp Main Window just a small badge in modern skin

Tags: mainwindow, winamp

I came to have the main window of Winamp in modern skin just as a small badge (about 30px height) with no possibility to resize. Functionality fine - appearance broken.

Changing the skin restored the main window, but back to modern skin it was a one-line-menu again. 
Research in forums brought up nothing helpful for me, just messing around with the config files didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this was helpful:

- open winamp
- toggle main window ON if necessary ("Alt-W")
- if necessary double-click to change from playbar to (what should be) normal window
- right-click on the remaining bar
- choose to see e.g. equalizer
- bar breaks at the bottom and shows remains of misplaced equalizer
- grab edges and resize

The new rectangle-information will be stored, winamp ist in normal shape again.

Hope that helps.